# How to prevent authetified users to update sensitive data

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Here is my rules and security model :

```
    {
        "rules": {
          "users": {   
            ".read" : "true",
            ".write" : "auth != null && data.val()===null",
            "$uid": {
              ".write" : "auth != null && auth.uid==$uid || data.val()===null"
            }
          }
    }
}
```

This a firebase for a mobile app.
Imagine the $UID has a branch named RATING. I don't want one authentifed user can update this information.
How can I prevent it ?
I could do maybe this by adding this line :

```
"rating": {
       ".write": "false"
        }
```

But in this case how can the app update the rating ?

I'm stuck on it, please give me some help cos I don't understand how I can write in firebase from a server side (like firebase hosting or webscript.io).

And forgive me this question if you think it's a stupid one.

Comment: What you suggest won't work, because you set write to true before and it won't change it back to false. Can you make clear what a user can change and who (or what) else can change the rest?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240940/how-do-you-authenticate-a-server-to-firebase. Maybe that answers your question?

Comment: Hi André Kool,Thanks for your answer I'm going to try that.

Comment: Also have a look at this question from yesterday that deals with splitting the data that should be writable in a situation such as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241129/how-to-set-this-firebase-rules/34242083#34242083

Comment: Frank, really interessting ! But in this case : how can I write to firebase ? I have to use one external server ? Can I use something as webscript.io or can I use the firebase hosting to run one script ?

Comment: Firebase currently doesn't offer a way for you to run your code on Firebase's servers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340542/how-to-write-custom-code-logic-when-using-firebase/31346677#31346677, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881973/can-i-host-a-listener-on-firebase