# Write in the Database from within the database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Hopefully the title is clear, I couldn't find a better name but if someone can improve it please update it, thanks.

I would like the Firebase database to write on a node if a certain condition is met. For example, if one node receives an input from a client (say an angular app) then another node in the database should write certain data, something like a callback that is fired when a node receives some data.

I know there are 4 rule types (.read .write .validate .indexOn), what I am thinking of is some kind of .callback rule that is fired and writes on a node after some other node has received an input.

Obviously this can be achieved via a server side script but Firebase is about a server-less approach so I am trying to understand what are its current limits and what I can do with it.

Thanks for your responses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I host a listener on Firebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881973/can-i-host-a-listener-on-firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Running the multi-location update client-side or on a server-side process that you control are currently the only ways to accomplish this.

There is currently no way to trigger updates based on modifications to the database *on Firebase servers*. It is no big secret that we've been working on such functionality for a while now, but we have made no announcement as to when that will be available.

Also see [Can I host a listener on Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881973/can-i-host-a-listener-on-firebase/22886180#22886180), which (I realize now) is probably a duplicate.